# Need to find and remove the two next words from X in string

Tags: javascript, string, split, splice

I am working on an assignment which I just cant figure out.

> "Prompt the user for a positive integer. If it is, find the first word in the text which has the same length as the provided number (X). From the string, remove the two words in the two positions after the position of X, and at the same place insert the copy of X. As a result, you should achieve a string that contains one word less and two of the same words close to each other."

I have managed to get X but cant get the the following words. Anyone have any suggestions? :)

```js
let spliceText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare mauris eget tortor accumsan posuere. Mauris pharetra pellentesque libero, ut cursus eros consectetur nec. Suspendisse id erat vitae tellus cursus rutrum ut sit amet nisi. Aliquam cursus ultrices nisl in vestibulum. Nunc lacinia metus a venenatis pretium. Nullam vitae tincidunt ante. Duis posuere, dolor ac accumsan consequat, ex mi congue sem, sit amet fringilla tellus velit at neque. Donec luctus mi eu ligula volutpat semper. Maecenas vulputate bibendum velit, at finibus velit consectetur sed. Maecenas commodo feugiat lorem, vitae eleifend velit iaculis ut. Duis ac suscipit nisl. Sed vel metus.";

let spliceText1 = spliceText.replaceAll(".", "").replaceAll(",", "");

let length = parseInt(prompt("Specify the word's length:")); {}

if (isNaN(length) && length < 0) {}

const match = spliceText1.split(' ').filter(x => x.length === length);

let newmatch = (match[0]);

console.log(newmatch)
```

Comment: `if (isNaN(length) && length < 0) {}` doesn't appear to do anything. You also have a stray `{}` block at the end of the line where `length` is defined. You need to retrieve the index of the word you find, set the next index to the value of x and delete (or set to empty string `""`) the next index. Personally, I would not use `map` but instead loop through with a for-next loop, retrieving the index on match and proceeding two more loops to make the changes.

Comment: Side note: `something.filter(/*...*/)[0]` is better written `something.find(/*...*/)`, more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find (but I don't think you want `find` for this).

Answer (score 1):

I'd divide the string up into an array of "words" (you've already found `split`), then find the index of the first word with the given length (for instance, with [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)). Then, that index `+ 1` and `+ 2` are the indexes of the next two words after it. You can remove those either by creating a new array and leaving them out, or by using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove them. I wouldn't remove punctuation except for the purposes of comparison (unless you've been told you can), since presumably you need to reassemble the string with the original punctuation intact (probably with [`join`][3]). (I'm assuming it's okay if two spaces in a row are converted to one or similar.)

Reiterating in list form:

- Get the desired word length
- Split the array on spaces
- Use `findIndex` to find the first word with that length (disregarding punctuation)
- Either create a new array leaving out the words at that index `+ 1` and `+ 2`, or use a call to `splice` to remove the next two entries from the array
- Recombine the string with `join`

*(We don't normally answer homework questions with working code, hence just having description.)*

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I got it all right now. Except the last part. Im struggling to get a copy of X.

Comment: @user1234567100 - A copy of X? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: From the string, remove the two words in the two positions after the position of X, and "at the same place insert the copy of X".  I tried by using .join but it doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: @user1234567100 - You get the index of the target word with `findIndex`. Then you know that the two words to remove are that index `+ 1` and `+ 2`. As I said above, you either create a new array leaving those out (`filter` passes the index of each value to the callback), or use `splice` to remove them. `splice` is probably good enough for your purposes, read up on it and it should be clear. When the array no longer has those two words, use `join`.

Comment: Yes I got it all right now! Thank so much for your help! :D Much appreciated!